# Get the maximum starting substring of the text node, such that the last word in it isn't truncated, and its length doesn't exceed a given limit

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

How do I select only n number of comments element using xsl. I am able to select n number of characters but that snaps in the middle of a word and makes it look ugly.

I have been able to get a count of total number of words in 'comments' node but not sure how to only show like 15 words if there are like a total of 20 there.

```
  <div class="NewsDescription">
  <xsl:value-of select="string-length(translate(normalize-space(@Comments),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',''))+1" /> 
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(@Comments,0,120)"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length(@Comments) &gt; 120">…</xsl:if>
    <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" class="ReadMore" style="font-size:11px ;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color :#00aeef">Read More</a> 
   </div>
```

Actual xml is like this. I am trying to rollup story pieces in "Related Stories' manner on the right side of a dynamic page.

```
<news>
   <title>Story title</title>
    <comments> story gist here..a couple of sentences.</comments>
    <content> actualy story </content>
```

Please help. I found this resources by Marc andersen but the xsl is too complex for me filter through and make use of myself..

http://sympmarc.com/2010/07/13/displaying-the-first-n-words-of-announcement-bodies-with-xsl-in-a-dvwp/

Some help from the XSL gurus will be appreciated..

Comment: Unfortunately I am on XSL 1.0

Comment: Sarika Thapaliya, Actually you don't want a known in advance number of words -- you want the maximum starting substring of the text node, such that the last word in it isn't truncated, and its length doesn't exceed a given limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a non-recursive, pure XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDigits" select="'0123456789'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAlhanum" select="concat($vLower, $vUpper, $vDigits)"/>

 <xsl:template match="comments">
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="not(string-length($pText) > 120)">
         <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
       </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:variable name="vTruncated" select="substring($pText, 1, 121)"/>
             <xsl:variable name="vPunct" 
                           select="translate($vTruncated, $vAlhanum, '')"/>
           <xsl:for-each select=
           "(document('')//node() | document('')//@* | document('')//namespace::*)
                           [not(position() > 121)]">

             <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="122 - position()"/>
             <xsl:variable name="vRemaining" select="substring($vTruncated, $vPos+1)"/>

             <xsl:if test=
              "contains($vPunct, substring($vTruncated, $vPos, 1))
              and
               contains($vAlhanum, substring($vTruncated, $vPos -1, 1))
              and
                 string-length(translate($vRemaining, $vPunct, ''))
                         = string-length($vRemaining)
              ">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring($vTruncated, 1, $vPos -1)"/>
             </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<news>
   <title>Story title</title>
    <comments> story gist here..a couple of sentences. Many more sentences ...
even some more text with lots of meaning and sense aaand a lot of humor. </comments>
    <content> actualy story </content>
</news>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 story gist here..a couple of sentences. Many more sentences ...
even some more text with lots of meaning and sense
```